# angular js call a method for a controller inside another controllers method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

i am writing a code in `angularjs` which loads the `controller` file as per session demands
i have a separate controller files for **`admin(let say ctrl1)`** and for **`staffs (ctrl2)`** and one **`common(ctrlComm)`** file which can be use any among them,now i want to call function of **`ctrl1` inside `ctrlComm`**, i do not want to write or paste the file code again,how can i do this.**Here is my code**.

**ctrl1:**

```
customerSupport.controller('studentSheet',['$scope',function($scope){

$scope.searchStudent=function(studentid){
        angService.getfromRemote('students/'+studentid)
            .success(function(response){
                if(response.success){
                        ...
                 }
           })
        }
    }])
```

**ctrlComm**

```
activities.controller('usersActivites',['$scope',function(){

$scope.studentdetail=function(studentid){
    console.log("how can i call the searchStudent if ctrl1 here ??");

    $scope.searchStudent(studentid);

   }


}])
```

Comment: instead you should be accessing the Student services in the activities controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing a function is a clear sign you need a [service.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

> Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using [dependency injection (DI)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

I believe you already have `angService` in place for this. Inject this service in  `usersActivites` and you are good to go. You can tweak your service to get student details directly. Create some function there like `angService.searchStudent` and from service return appropriate response.

Comment: thaks it works, what i need to do now is,write my controller search function inside service then it will work every where. thanx once again